# How to use auto-layout on a grid?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but I have a grid like that below and have been futzing around with Auto-layout with only limited success. Currently the cells are individual `UILabels` that are embedded in `UIViews`. These views are inside a `UIViewController`. I've used auto-layout to center the views but this does not solve the problem laying out the labels. I've looked a bit at Container views, but it seems that every cell has to be the same size. Tables? It seems to me that I'd have the same problem in custom `table view cell` classes. I'm exploring this anyway.

The views look like this:

Can someone tell me a good way to solve this.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? Are your labels suppose to be equal widths? Equidistant? Centered?

Comment: The labels are different widths. How do I adjust every one to fit on different size devices? Right now, the layout looks good on an iPhone 6, but on an iPhone 5, the right side is truncated.

Comment: Is there a specific label you want to be able to shrink, or do you want them all to proportionally shrink in relation to the view size?

Comment: Good question. I could shrink the wide label

Comment: So im assuming you have a width constraint on the wide label? If so, delete it and just put horizontal spacing constraints from the labels to its left and right. That would cause auto layout to shrink the wide label as the screen gets shrunk. That is all provided you have leading and trailing constraints from the gray view to its super view. Also, your right label should have  a trailing space constraint rather than a leading space constraint.

Comment: I just had another thought on this.. While I can shrink the wide label, I do want the labels in each column to be the same width.

Comment: I wish there was a grid controller that I could simply plug in.

Comment: In UICollectionView, don't the cells all have to be the same sizes?

Comment: No, you can use `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to dynamically size your cells.

Comment: I would use a table view with a cell containing 4 labels arranged like you have in your image.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll respond asap

Comment: I ended up using a table view with a custom cell. It's interesting how tough this is and especially to layout complex cells for different device types/sizes.